# What is the correct way to set httpheaders to httprequest in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, httprequest, angular-http-interceptors

i have a **HttpInterceptor** with next code:

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Autorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
}
```

but not set the autorization header in request like next image
[request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjVZ1.png)

Comment: You misspelled Authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
const _req = req.clone({
  headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')),
});

return next.handle(_req);
```